# How do I launch Anaconda to commence Python programming using Jupyter notebooks or Jupyter lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-3.7, anaconda3

I installed the Anaconda program on my Microsoft Surface Pro laptop. After installation, I tried to launch the program that should apparently access me to Jupyter notebooks or Jupyter Lab on a Windows 10 Platform. The outcome was the home screen of the PC. In contrast, installing IDLE for Windows was smooth and prograaming in Python had no complications. I would deeply appreciate any assistance

Comment: Try this: Run Anaconda Prompt, and type `jupyter notebook`. Let me know if that works. Thanks!

Comment: You can  only be launch anaconda from either from anaconda command prompt or anaconda navigator